# If I sell my PS4 game disc and buy a digital version, can I still access my saved game?

Tags: ps4

If I sell my PS4 game disc and buy a digital version, can I still access my original saved game, or my progress?

I have the Resident Evil 2 remake on a disc. I finished the game already and I'm thinking of selling the disc and buying it digitally. If I do this, can I still access my saved data and progress on the digital version?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes. Your save game will be compatible for both the physical and digital version of the game.

There is an exception, however.

Depending on the game, if the physical and digital versions are not of the same region, your save game might not work.

For example, Persona 5 (JPN) and Persona 5 (EU) are not compatible with each other.

Comment: Also you could find that the Downloadable game didn't include some DLC which you already (unknowingly in some cases) had on disc. I can't think of any specifics right now, but having DLC installed can effect game saves so they don't work without 'repurchasing' the DLC.

Comment: @djsmiley2k. I'm only aware of one game that did something like that: Bioshock 2 (PS3). The game shipped with a "download" code, but the DLC was already on disk. People who bought the game second-hand had to purchase the DLC separately, even though it was already on disk. Not sure if that's the same or something different, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data is all saved on the PS4 / Storage Device not the disc. All of your data should still be there.

Comment: Just because the data is saved on your hard drive it doesn't mean that the disc version and the digital version have compatible save files. It varies by game, I have personally ran into this problem.